# 8086 Assembly: Multiply two 16 bit numbers to yield a 32 bit result without using the mul instruction

Tags: assembly, masm, x86-16

In understanding the benefits of using x86 assembly language, I am trying to write as an excercise, a **16x16 bit** multiplication routine which takes in **two unsigned** 16 bit values and *multiplies* them using *shifting* and *addin*g, and stores the final 32 bit result in **DX:AX**.

There is no problem running the code (in other words, it compiles just fine and runs with my linked program), however the code is not giving the expected multiplication outcome.

This is what I have come up with so far:

In theory this should be giving me the unsigned 32 bit result in DX:AX.

When I use this code in my program, the **lower 16 bits** of the **32 bit** result (or in other words, the AX portion) are correct and show up just fine. The **higher 16 bits** of the 32 bit result (the DX portion) are **not correct**.

**Could anyone help me figure out what it is that I'm doing wrong?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: I doubt this is really faster than a simple `mov ax, cx; mul bx`. Or are you trying this as an exercise?

Comment: @PMF Mainly an exercise to understand how it could be done, though it would be very interesting to see something that is faster than using the mul instruction (since apparently it is just behind div as the slowest instruction on the 8086).

Comment: Yea, in the first asm book I read, some 20 years ago, they wrote a calculator program, but since back then mul and div indeed were terribly slow, they used bitwise shifts like you do here. But I would really be surprised if that was still the case with todays microcode architectures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though you need to shift part of the multiplicand into another register after `add bx, bx`. This is because each time you shift bx without shifting the carry, the top bit becomes truncated. So your original code just stores the sum of carries from adding bx to ax, rather than the upper part of the multiplication solution, in dx.

Try this after the label AddToResult:

```
@AddToResult:
    add   bx,bx     ; add instead of shift?
    adc   di,di     ; shift part of multiplicand.
    or    cx,cx     ; fast zero check
    jnz   @lp
```

I also chose di for the upper 16 bits of the multiplicand because it's already being used to add the carry to the solution.

Comment: I tried to work out what was going wrong with my code by hand, and after seeing your suggestion and answer, I realize that it is exactly what I was missing in the code I posted initially. Do you think there is a more efficient way to do this in fewer instructions?

Comment: I guess you could remove the code before the loop that checks if both bx and cx are 0. Your result will still be 0, and multiplying by 0 isn't special enough to have a special case.